# Rule doesn't match when the amount is between 8.7 and 8.89

Tags: drools

The drl's `when` condition looks something like below. The equals operator for the amount works fine for any amount except in the range from 8.7 to 8.89. It works for 1.01, 4.45, 8.55 or 8.69. But the mentioned range doesn't work only for equals operator. Other operators like `<=` or `>=` works. Anyone faced this issue before? if so, why is it happening for that range?

```
txnRuleInfo: TransactionRuleInfo(
    transactionInfo.transactionAmount==8.7,
    transactionInfo.transactionType==TransactionType.SALE
)
```

Comment: What is the data type of `transactionAmount`? If it's a double, have you verified the precision of your comparison?

Comment: It is a BigDecimal format. It works for others numbers like 8.67 or 8.6.

Comment: Folks..any of you faced this issue? Please let me know.

Comment: What version of Drools are you using please? If not the latest, please try the latest version.